# how to color each row separately and dynamically using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a table dynamically in javascript
and now I would like to add some functions to it.
I mean whenever I hover on each row, the row color changes and when I click on each row I get the index of that row.
How is it possible?

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="show_member">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>نام</th>
    <th>نام به لاتین</th>
    <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
    <th>نام خانوادگی به لاتین</th>
    <th>کد ملی</th>
    <th>شماره استخدام</th>
    <th>پست الکترونیکی(Email)</th>
    <th>نام کاربری</th>
    <th>رمز عبور</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

and here I don't know why only the last row is colored
thanks

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        $name = $row['first_name'];
        $name2 = $row['first_name2'];
        $lastname = $row['last_name'];
        $lastname2 = $row['last_name2'];
        $mellicode = $row['melli_code'];
        $estekhdamnum = $row['estekhdam_num'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];

echo("<script type='text/javascript'>

var table = document.getElementById('show_member');

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(i);
i = i+1;
// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the new <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = '$name';
cell2.innerHTML = '$name2';
cell3.innerHTML = '$lastname';
cell4.innerHTML = '$lastname2';
cell5.innerHTML = '$mellicode';
cell6.innerHTML = '$estekhdamnum';
cell7.innerHTML = '$email';
cell8.innerHTML = '$username';
cell9.innerHTML = '$password';

</script>"

);

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var index = 0;
var table = document.getElementById("show_member");
var length = table.rows.length;
var row;
alert(length);
for(index=1;index<table.rows.length-2;index++){
    row = table.rows[index];
    row.onmouseover = function(){
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    row.onmouseout = function(){
        row.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
index = index+1;
table.rows[index].style.backgroundColor = 'green';


</script>
```

Comment: because you only set 'green' as background-color for the last row. you need to put that part into your loop to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First to change the row color on hover :

```
$('tr').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Now to get the index of the row that you clicked :

```
$('tr').hover(function(){
  alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

Comment: There's no jquery tag on this question.

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that the answer has to be in pure Javascript wither :p

Comment: @Ashiq Muhammed it is self explanatory since the question is tagged as javascript and he provided javascript code.

Comment: I never thought that jquery can also solve my problem because I didn't know jquery

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @saeeddoozandeh You should really try your hands at jQuery. It will help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(index=1;index<table.rows.length-2;index++){
    row = table.rows[index];
    row.onmouseover = function(){
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    row.onmouseout = function(){
        row.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}
index = index+1;
table.rows[index].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

To:

```
for(index=1;index<table.rows.length-2;index++){
    row = table.rows[index];
    row.onmouseover = function(){
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    row.onmouseout = function(){
        row.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
table.rows[index].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

Comment: that wont work. you need to remove the "index = index + 1" part or you will only change every second row.

Comment: It would be better to point out what exactly the change is, rather than leaving it as a find-the-difference exercise. Especially, when it is just a brace's position.

Comment: @wayneOS - fixed ;)